# JSESSIONID getting twice in cookie

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jboss, struts

I am using jboss 5.1 server and struts framework . The following are usecases

### Usecase 1

1)Cleared the browser cache and loaded browser with my application url
(say /loadLogin.do)

2)In code `httpSession = request.getSession(false);` when i check httpSession its not null and has some jessionid say 123

3)Now i invalidate the session `httpSession.invalidate();`

4)Again i create a new session `httpSession = request.getSession()`; now this time a new jessionid is created say 456

5)Finally when i check my cookie it shows 2(two) jessionid's

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=123.node1; Path=/loadLogin  
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=456.node1; Path=/loadLogin
```

### Usecase 2

1)Don't clear cache

2)Suppose the browser already has the url (i.e. login to the app and then logout and then try logging in again , this time browser shows url in its dropdown)

3)This time when i check cookie only 1 jessionid is present ..

Can someone plz tell me , is the how the server behaves , or something to do with the way session is being handled in application

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with this problem too half year ago. it was very frustrating problem. But I solved it.
You first cancel new created session and then create new one.

```
if (getHttpRequest().getSession(false).isNew() == false) {
  getHttpRequest().getSession(false).invalidate();
  getHttpRequest().getSession(true);
}
```